# React VitePWA workbox options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps, vite

has anyone had a similar problem and maybe someone knows how to solve it

I use React + VitePWA and and I need to configure the workbox settings, so that any files with the extension.csv should use NetworkFirst strategy how can i understand is that url pattern problem or not

for example my url - https://testing.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/data.csv?x-id=GetObject

but i still get this [image] from disk cache

```
       globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html}', '**/*.{svg,png,jpg,gif}'],
       runtimeCaching: [
         {
           urlPattern: /data\/(.*?)/,
           handler: 'NetworkFirst',
           options: {
             cacheName: 'interface-cache',
           },
         },
       ],
     },
```

Comment: Did you succeed somehow ?